# Como aplicar filtros numa relação belongsToMany em Laravel 5.8?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Tenho uma tabela `posts`, uma tabela `categorias`  e uma tabela pivot `categoria_post`, onde um post pode estar associado a muitas ou nenhuma categoria.

No meu model `categoria` e `post` tenho respectivamente os métododos `categorias` e `posts` numa relação `belongsToMany`.

```
public function posts(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\post','categoria_post','categoria_id','post_id');
    }

public function categorias(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\categoria','categoria_post','post_id','categoria_id');
}
```

Na tabela posts tenho um campo `is_active` e `rate`.

Eu quero apresentar assim no browser:

1. Mostrar a lista dos `8 posts mais votados (rate)` e `ativos (is_active==1)` e que estão associados ao menos a uma categoria,
2. Exibir uma lista de todas as categorias e todos os posts ativos (is_active==1) que estão relacionados a cada uma delas.

BROWSER

---

```
(os 8 posts ativos mais votados)
post 1, post 2, post 3, post 4, post 5, post 6, post 7, post 8 


(Todos os posts ativos por categoria)

Categoria 1
post 1, post 2,

categoria 2
post 1, post 3,

categoria 2
post 1, post 3, post 7,

...
```

Como consigo isso usando o menor numero de foreach possível?

Existe alguma maneira de no Modelo Categoria dentro da função posts (belongToMany) filtrar somente os posts ativos (is_active==1)?

Answer (score 0):

Se estiver criando os modelos no padrão do Eloquent, basta adicionar as condições

Exemplo:

```
$posts = App\Post::where('is_active' => 1)->orderBy('rate', 'desc')->take(8)->get();
```